# Detecting media buttons not working (Xamarin.Forms)

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm currently developing a music player application for Android in Xamarin.Forms and I have encountered an issue with detecting the forward (next song) and backward (previous song) media buttons on any Bluetooth device.

I've tried using a BroadcastReceiver but no matter what I do the `OnReceive` function gets called only when the play/pause button is pressed. I've tried two different Bluetooth headphones and both haven't yielded any results.

I have been stumped by this problem for quite some time, so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you use any packages or which part of code caused this issue?

Comment: I'm not sure if I got your question. I'm trying to detect when the user presses the forward and backward buttons on their headphones. I've tried using a BroadcastReceiver but to no avail.

Comment: Since I haven't found a solution, I just used a workaround specific to my application.
In case someone has the setup as mine, I'll write the solution. I'm using the XamarinMediaManager plugin to play audio. Since it restarts the current song when I press the forward button, I check for that using StateChanged and play the next song. Sadly, the backward button can't work with this workaround.